Controlling TP-Link switch by sending commands to SSH CLI from python
What I want to do
I've run into problems of controlling my TP-Link TL-SG2218. It has embedded SSH CLI on vendor firmware. And using standard console linux console SSH client CLI works really PERFECT.
Here's example what I'm doing (I'm enabling port №10):
unit-1@unit1:~$ ssh admin@192.168.21.79
admin@192.168.21.79's password: 
TL-SG3428>enable
TL-SG3428#configure
TL-SG3428(config)#interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/10
TL-SG3428(config-if)#no shutdown
TL-SG3428(config-if)#exit
TL-SG3428(config)#exit
TL-SG3428#copy running-config startup-config 
 Start to save user config as the Next Startup Config file......
 Saving user config OK!
TL-SG3428#exit
TL-SG3428>exit
Connection to 192.168.21.79 closed.
unit-1@unit1:~$ 

So, works really fast and perfect
And I need to do the same thing, but from python code
What I've tried:
Solution 1
Use standard SSH library (paramiko)
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(ip, username=login, password=password, auth_timeout=20,
                             channel_timeout=20)
ssh.exec_command(command)

Getting EOF-error when using standard exec_command method
Solution 2
Using paramiko, but implement interactive shell(use channel)
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(ip, username=login, password=password, auth_timeout=20,
                             channel_timeout=20)
channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
self.channel.send(command.encode("UTF-8"))
buff = ''
while "#" not in buff and ">" not in buff:
    resp = self.channel.recv(4096)
    buff += resp.decode("UTF-8")
    print(buff)
print(buff)

It's stuck in an endless loop. And if I remove while cycle for reading response, and just passing commands with small pauses, it wasn't work
Solution 3 (Netmiko)
I found this python lib: netmiko
Using this code I was finally able to correctly execute commands
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
switch = {
    'device_type': 'tplink_jetstream',
    'host': ip,
    'username': login,
    'password': password
}
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**switch)
net_connect.send_command(command) 

But I ran into fact, that netmiko works in ~50% cases when I ran full scenario.
And in another 50% cases I always get this exception (absolutely randomly, after random command)
[EXECUTING]enable
Already in admin level.

[EXECUTING]configure

TL-SG3428#configure

[EXECUTING]interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/10
INFO:     172.22.0.1:55758 - "POST /disable_switch HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 401, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 70, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 186, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 65, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 756, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 776, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 297, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 77, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 72, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 222, in __aexit__
    await self.gen.athrow(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/concurrency.py", line 35, in contextmanager_in_threadpool
    raise e
netmiko.exceptions.ReadTimeout: 
Pattern not detected: 'TL\\-SG3428\\(config\\)\\#' in output.

Things you might try to fix this:

1. Explicitly set your pattern using the expect_string argument.
2. Increase the read_timeout to a larger value.

You can also look at the Netmiko session_log or debug log for more information.

I'm really running out of nerves.
What you can suggest?
I'm thinking of two ways:

Use console linux ssh client from python, something like Popen or so, and communicate with it?
Maybe fine tune expect_string pattern in netmiko? (because it's basically working, just not always)
Maybe something else? I'm just needed simple way to run CLI command and get results, as do it in linux SSH client?


Try using Pexpect Lib(

https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect
)

Pexpect is a python module that allows spawn child applications, controle then, and respond expected patterns in output.
import pexpect

# Start the SSH connection to the switch
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh admin@192.168.21.79')

# Wait for the password prompt and send the password
child.expect("password:")
child.sendline('your_password_here')  # Replace 'your_password_here' with the correct password

# Wait for the switch prompt
child.expect('TL-SG3428>')

# Send the 'enable' command
child.sendline('enable')

# Wait for the privileged mode prompt
child.expect('TL-SG3428#')

# Send the 'configure' command
child.sendline('configure')

# Wait for the global configuration prompt
child.expect('TL-SG3428\(config\)#')

# Send the command to enter the specified interface
child.sendline('interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/10')

# Wait for the interface configuration prompt
child.expect('TL-SG3428\(config-if\)#')

# Send the 'no shutdown' command
child.sendline('no shutdown')

# Exit interface configuration mode
child.sendline('exit')

# Wait for the global configuration prompt
child.expect('TL-SG3428\(config\)#')

# Exit global configuration mode
child.sendline('exit')

# Wait for the privileged mode prompt
child.expect('TL-SG3428#')

# Send the command to save the configuration
child.sendline('copy running-config startup-config')

# Wait for the save confirmation message
child.expect('Saving user config OK!')

# Exit privileged mode
child.sendline('exit')

# Exit EXEC mode
child.expect('TL-SG3428>')

# Close the SSH session
child.sendline('exit')

# Wait for the connection to close
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)

# Print the complete session output
print(child.before.decode('utf-8'))

